# jquery disable document function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple function that needs to be updated with the current textarea.

```
  $(document).on("keydown", updated_textarea_var, function (e) {
     // do stuff
  });
```

So to do this, I disable the previous function and run a new function with the updated variable. The problem is the previous function is not disabling.

```
$(selector).off();
```

My variables are correct. Can .off() be used with a document function? Or am I using it improperly?
Or perhaps there's a better way to do this?

Comment: @minitech selector is the previous updated_textarea_var.

Comment: need to show code that you are using to `disable`. A few snippets don't tell anyone much

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.off()` must be used with the same selector and event that `.on()` was used with.  So, to unhook this:

```
$(document).on("keydown", updated_textarea_var, function (e) {
```

you would use this:

```
$(document).off("keydown", updated_textarea_var);
```

You must target the same object (the one the original event was attached to) and you must target the appropriate event so jQuery knows which event handlers to remove.  You can optionally target the secondary selector and/or the actual callback function if you want a finer grained match for what to remove.

---

However, since you are using delegated event handling, you may not have to turn the event handling off and back on.  If we understood more about what you're actually trying to do, there may be a cleaner option.

---

For example, if you're just trying to change which textarea is being targeted by the event handler, then you can use a class name in the event handler (let's say there's a class name called "target") like this:

```
$(document).on("keydown", ".target", function (e) {
```

And, then to change which textarea the event handler is in action for, you just remove the class name from one textarea and add it to another.  This is a key feature of delegated event handling.

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling it'd be something like that. The reason it has to change is because the target element will change from "last" to "second to last" and vice versa

Comment: @Mathew - if you use a class name on the target element and pass that class name here `$(document).on("keydown", ".target", function (e) {`, then all you have to do to change the target element is remove the class name from one element and add it to another.  That is the beauty of delegated event handling.